# Using RadToolTip with RadComboBox without using ItemTempalte

Tags: asp.net, telerik, tooltip, radcombobox

Is there a way to connect a RadToolTip to each item within a RadComboBox (having a different tool tip come up for each item in the combo box) without having to use the ItemTemplate of the RadComboBox?  The reason is because I like the built-in implementation of the combo box styles, etc. and don't want to write it all from scratch within the ItemTemplate.  I am trying to have a tool tip come up when I am hovering over an item in my combo box which shows some more information about that item.  Basically giving the user a little more information before making their selection.

Updated: I need the tool tip to support HTML or even a RadGrid.  It cannot just be a text tool tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that there is no way to add a RadToolTip to the items without using the Item Template.  What about the styling would be too difficult to replicate using the Item Template?